# Custom adapter view not updating correctly

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-adapterview

Ok, I have a custom AdapterView. Whenever I detect a long click, I call a method to change a custom editable status.

```
public void setEditing(boolean editing) {
    this.editing = editing;
    //Set editing to children
    for (int i=0; i < getChildCount(); i++){
        ((PresentationPickerGalleryCellView)getChildAt(i)).setEditing(editing);
        if (editing == true)
            getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //((PresentationPickerGalleryCellView)getChildAt(i)).deleteImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

It's executed in the main thread as far as I am concerned.
Now, if I call:

```
getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

It hides the whole view **correctly** when editing==true. But if I call:

```
((PresentationPickerGalleryCellView)getChildAt(i)).deleteImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The deleteImageButton is a button inside the cell. **It won't show the deleteImageButton at all**. I tried invalidate, postInvalidate, layout, requestLayout, refreshDrawableState, but nothing...

Any ideas?

Comment: Should you not also make the whole cell visible? if the cell is invisible, making just the button inside cell visible won't help.

Comment: Of course, the whole cell is visible. I was just testing the difference between hiding the whole cell or showing the button inside the cell

Answer (score 0):

Ok...
It seems if I set View.GONE at the beginning, and then I try to set View.VISIBLE, it won't show the button...
I have to work only with View.INVISIBLE and View.VISIBLE :/